# Preparing soluble salts from acids and soluble and insoluble reactants

Tags: acid-base

**3.15**: Explain why, if soluble salts are prepared from an acid and an insoluble reactant:
a) Excess of the reactant is added
b) The excess reactant is removed
c) The solution remaining is only salt and water

**3.16**: Explain why, is soluble salts are prepared from an acid and a soluble reactant:
a) Titration must be used
b) The acid and the soluble reactant are then mixed in the correct proportions
c) The solution remaining, after reaction, is only salt and water.

These are two points in the GCSE specification I do not completely understand. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

3.15 a)To ensure that all the acid has reacted, such that the amount of salt you 
have prepared is indeed the amount you planned to prepare. b)To remove impurities from the salt you have prepared. c)Since you have reacted all the acid and removed all the impurities, what is remaining is evidently salt and water.

3.16 a)Now, the key idea is that you want to prepare a precise amount of the pure salt in solution, meaning to have **no acid or any of the other soluble reactant contaminating your sample of aqueous salt**. This is the reason why you need to be very precise when mixing your reactants because you cannot add more or less. Remember that since the reactants and product is in the same phase, you have no way of removing one from the other easily. b) Remember that we want a precise amount of the salt and no excess acid or any of the other reactant. c) Since all the acid and the other reactant has reacted, the only products in the solution are water and salt (typical of an acid-base, acid-metal reaction).

Hope you found this useful!